# Push Notifications With Firebase, Node.js, and Google Cloud Messaging for iOS app

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Firebase, Node.js, and Google Cloud Messaging to send push notifications for an iOS app. Below is the Node.js code

```
var Firebase = require('firebase'),
    gcm = require('node-gcm')
    ;
var pushRef = new Firebase("https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com/ios/queue/tasks");

pushRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

    console.log("child added event registers");

    var notificationData = snapshot.val();
    sendNotification(notificationData);
    snapshot.ref().remove();

});

function sendNotification(notificationData) {

    var message = new gcm.Message({
      notification: {
        title: "Title",
        body: notificationData.message
      }
    });

    var sender = new gcm.Sender(<my Google Server Key>);
    var registrationTokens = [notificationData.recipientId];

    console.log("about to send message");
    console.log("this is the registration token: " + registrationTokens);

    sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: registrationTokens }, 10, function (err, response) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
}
```

There are no errors, and all of the console.log statements register. However, I never receive a push notification on my device. Here is the console.log(response):

```
{ multicast_id: 7398179070839209000,
  success: 1,
  failure: 0,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { message_id: '0:1457564370785913%939a5f18939a5f18' } ] }
```

What might be going on? It looks like things should be working, but they aren't

Comment: Can you add `priority: 'high'` to your message? We recently had an issue where that was required to deliver notifications to iOS devices (unless the app was already active).

Answer (score 5):

By default messages are sent with standard priority, which according to [Google Cloud Messaging docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message):

> This is the default priority for message delivery. Normal priority messages won't open network connections on a sleeping device, and their delivery may be delayed to conserve battery. For less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email or other data to sync, choose normal delivery priority.

Somehow this normal priority seems to [affect iOS more than Android apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/60).

To get the messages delivered immediately, you'll want to add `priority: 'high'` to you message:

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
  priority : "high",
  notification: {
    title: "Title",
    body: notificationData.message
  }
});
```

Comment: Today GCM was sending two pushes. When I took out the `"priority: 'high'"`, it started behaving normally. Seems like the `priority` key behaves strangely sometimes