# The notification not showing on device when push by firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow google [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging) to make push notification for my app. I send a push notification out from the Firebase console, banner or popup of notification not appear on my iPhone, but this message is shown on the console of Xcode
[image]

**Solved**:

You should be turning on `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled`

Comment: If the app is backgrounded, be sure to send the message with high priority. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35906522/209103. Aside from that: include the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Thank for you help but I solved this problem by turn on `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled `

Comment: Good to hear Alan. Can you write up an answer of what you did and how that fixed your problem? It may be useful for others who are having a similar problem.

Comment: I am working on Firebase push notification but I am confused between Firebase Notification and Firebase Cloud Messaging. What is the Difference ?